# EXCEL - Dropdown Lists and Hiding Columns

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu

Hi I'm looking for help!

Question:
Is there a way to hide multiple columns based on a selection in a dropdown list?

Explanation:
I have created an excel doc to use as a holiday Calendar for everyone in my team. Each person has a tab/sheet that tracks what days they have booked as holiday ect.

I then have a tab/sheet that collates all of this info and auto updates based on the individuals sheet. This is all done by basic formulas.
i.e if Fred books May 1st off marked by an X the main calendar sheet shows an X in the cell for the same date and name. (=Fred!$B$9)

Peoples names are in Rows, Days & Months in Columns.

As this main sheet has all of the days of the year (Grouped by Month) it spans from column B - NC.

I have created a dropdown list of Months via 'Data Validation' but I can't seem to figure out how to select the month from the dropdown list and only the columns associated with that month to show.

Any help would be great, I'm hoping it's a really simple and obvious work around that I have just over looked.

Thanks  SJM

Image attached is of how I have set out the columns highlighted is the Months dropdown list.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it in Excel without a VBA macro. So I created a macro that may help you. However, this specific macro I made only works if:

- your date format is mm/dd/yyyy, like in the US (you can change the format in Excel if you need);
- your drop-down month selection is in *numbers*;
- your drop-down month selection is on the same sheet as your calendar;
- you only have dates from one year (exclusively 2023 for example).

Else, I may need to make adjustments later to fit your need.

[See this button with a macro assigned.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bsF2.png)

[And again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjviS.png)

In this code you can edit the name of your calendar sheet, the row with your dates and the cell that has your drop-down value (at lines 9, 10 and 11).

```html
Sub CollapseColumnsByMonth()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim targetMonth As Integer
Dim targetYear As Integer
Dim col As Range
Dim cell As Range

' Edit these values for your needs
Dim calendarSheetName As String: calendarSheetName = "Sheet1"
Dim RowOfDateHeaders As Integer: RowOfDateHeaders = 1
Dim selectionCell As String: selectionCell = "A2"

' Get values from your workbook
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(calendarSheetName)
targetMonth = ws.Range(selectionCell)

' Unhide all columns before the process
ws.Columns.Hidden = False

' Loop through each cell in the RowOfDateHeaders
For Each cell In ws.Rows(RowOfDateHeaders).Cells
    ' Check if the cell value is a date
    If IsDate(cell.Value) Then
        ' Check if the date matches the desired month
        If Month(cell.Value) <> targetMonthThen Then
            ' Get the column associated with the target date
            Set col = ws.Columns(cell.Column)
            
            ' Collapse the column
            col.Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

To use this code, access the VBA screen in Excel by pressing Alt + F11.
Then you can paste this code in the ['ThisWorkbook' container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1DJJ.png).

Then you need to access the [Developer tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcoml.png) to put a button on your sheet. If the Developer tab is hidden for you and you don't know how to access it, please look it up. Then [assign the new macro and press OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGPBn.png).

If your colleagues will also work with this workbook, they will need to enable macro's to be able to use that button.

I hope this helps a bit and/or gives you some inspiration to take this a bit further to get just what you need if you want.

Kind regards,